# How to Remove dynamically added controls in the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am adding controls dynamically in the below div when you click a button like this:

```
                                <div class="column" id="addkey" style="width: 200px">

                                </div>
                                <div class="column" id="main1" style="width: 150px">

                                </div>
                                <div class="column" id="docmanindex" style="width: 150px">

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

function AddPrimaryClick() {

```
        var selectedprimarykey = $("#ddlprimarykey :selected").text();

        var one = chkkeyId + i;

        var two = radioId + i;

        var three = chkindxid + i;



        $('#addkey').append('<input type="checkbox"' + ' id = ' + one + '/> ' + selectedprimarykey + '<br />' + '<br />');

        $('#main1').append('<input type="radio" ' + ' id = ' + two + '/> ' + '<br />' + '<br />');

        $('#docmanindex').append('<input type="checkbox" ' + ' id = ' + three + '/> ' + '<br />' + '<br />');

        i = i + 1;



    };
```

How do i remove above controls which are checked on a button click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
 $("input:checked").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="radio" name="test" />
<input type="radio" name="test" />
<button id="button">
  Remove
</button>
```

Comment: @sin_user Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: I also need to remove other controls(not checked) that are next to the check box checked. They are also added dynamically from the code I mentioned above.I tried to remove by hardcoding the id  $("#mainkey1/").remove(); but it didn't work.Can you please advice? Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: @sin_user If you already tried to remove it by hardcoding the id and it didn't work then there seems to be another issue. Did you check the console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the checked check boxes and checked radio buttons and remove it using jquery remove() function

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked, input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```